# Handling multiple exceptions in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, exception

I have a tiny web-server written in Python 3 using [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) which calls the function `translate()` in method `do_GET()` like this:

```
class httpd(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.wfile.write(bytes(f'{translate(var[0])}', 'utf-8'))
```

Now in this `translate()` function I have several conditional statements and `try` and `except` blocks roughly like this:

```
def translate(param):
    try:
        # do something
    except SomeError as some_err:
        print("Error: " % some_err)
        return ""

    if True:
        try:
            # do something
        except SomeOtherError as some_other_err:
            print("Error: " % some_other_err)
            return ""
        except SomeThirdError as some_third_err:
            print("Third error: " % some_third_err)
            return ""
    else:
        # additional try and except blocks which print an error and
        # return an empty string
```

The code above is simplified, but in principle I return an empty string if an exception happens and thus my web server returns nothing to client if an exception happens.

Is there a more manageable way to handle this? Specifically, I'm looking to:

- Avoid catching each error via a separate `except` section, while still supporting an error message dependent on error type.
- Avoid writing multiple `try` / `except` statements, often nested, within my function.

---

**Note:** This is a copy of [this now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901075/pythonic-way-to-handle-exceptions-in-functions). The solution from that post is included below, but other answers are welcome.

Comment: This is a *very broad* question. Exception handling is very specific to the use cases involved, and it could well be that your actual application could avoid a bunch of exceptions altogether if restructured. But with the overly generic `Something..Error` exceptions here with `do something` code there is only very broad advice we can give. Context managers could help, but are not a general fits-all solution. Catching a base exception is another. Using `except (Exc1, Exc2, Exc3)` then dispatching from there in the exception handler is a 3rd. These all have different characterstics.

Comment: But writing all that down is going to require something approaching publishable book status, so I've closed this as Too Broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)? To alleviate your concern about custom error messages, you can feed a dictionary mapping error classes to messages of your choice.

Since different operations require different errors to be handled, you can use multiple `with` statements, feeding different errors as arguments each time.

Here's a contrived example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def error_handling(msg, *exceptions):
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions as my_error:
        print(msg[my_error.__class__], my_error)
        return ''

def do_stuff(d, key, index):

    custom_msg = {IndexError: 'You have an Index Error!',
                  KeyError: 'You have a Key Error!'}

    with error_handling(custom_msg, IndexError, KeyError):
        return d[key][index]

# example prints "You have an Index Error! list index out of range"; then returns ''
do_stuff({'a': [0, 1, 2]}, 'a', 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if having nested `try` blocks is absolutely necessary in your logic, but I'd try a single `try` block with a custom `Exception` class. Something like this:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    """Generic error message."""
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__doc__

class SomeError(MyException):
    """SomeError message."""
    pass

class SomeOtherError(MyException):
    """SomeOtherError message."""
    pass

class SomeThirdError(MyException):
    """SomeThirdError message."""
    pass



def translate(param):
    try:
        # do something
        ...
        if cond1:
            raise SomeError()
        ...
        if cond2:
            raise SomeOtherError()
        ...
        if cond3:
            raise SomeThirdError()
        ...

    except MyException as err:
        print(err)
        return ""
```

Comment: @jpp If you raise any subclassed exception you will output the proper message given that you have `return self.__doc__` in the `__str__` method of base class, that's the way sub-classes and inheritance works. I've update the example just to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

How about to define a function that has a dictionary contained the whole errors and responses. in this case you can catch an exception one time and send it to a handler

UPDATE :

```
def handle (e) :

exp = {'IOError' : 'NO such a file in dir ...! ' ,
       'KeyboardInterrupt' : 'Exiting ... (Keyboard interruption)',
       'IndexError' : ' a sequence subscript is out of range' ,
       'NameError' : 'a local or global name is not found'}

for key , value in exp.items() :
    if e == key :
        print (value) #or do whatever you want

def test() :
    try :
        f = open('no-file' , 'r')
    except Exception as e :
        handle (type(e).__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    test()
```

Comment: Probably goes without saying, but the `...` bit is relevant here, it would be helpful if you can fill them in with a trivial example users can run.

Comment: you're right, I hope this helps.